# Multiple loops in to calculate dependent variables

Tags: algorithm, matlab, loops

I have two equations A and B and I have to calculate A and B by using Thomas algorithm.
The problem is that the variable of B depends on the matrix coefficients of A. So in each iteration I must calculate the two variables but the Thomas algorithm uses two steps(forward elimination and backward substitution) and in each step, I have a loop.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Please be more specific. What form do your equations have? How many unknowns are there?

Comment: Please provide an example of the code that you have tried.  Also, please be careful of what you ask. I could completely correctly answer:" Yes. There is a way to do that."  :)

Comment: Please see [ask], and also the links therein. You'll get more out of Stack Overflow if you ask questions in the right way. As it stands, it is not possible to give a useful answer to your question, as it is not at all clear what it is that you are asking. As Strom said, the answer to your question now is just "yes", but I'm sure that is not what you are here for. We would need a lot more detail to give a proper answer.